# Configure database with keycloak using database service name

Tags: database, docker, oracle11g, docker-compose, keycloak

I have already successfully configured a database with `keycloak` using database `SID` and following configuration. However, I have to configure another database which doesn't has `SID` but with a `service name` in `docker-compose` file. I couldn't find a way to configure database to `keycloak` using it's `service name`.

**Configuration using SID in docker-compose file**

```
         - name: DB_VENDOR
           value: ORACLE
         - name: DB_ADDR
           value: xxx.xx.xx.xxx
         - name: DB_PORT
           value: "1521"
         - name: DB_DATABASE
           value: sid_name
         - name: DB_USER
           value: db_user_name
         - name: DB_PASSWORD
           value: ******
```

When I tried to use `service name` instead of `SID` as value for `DB_DATABASE` it gave  following error.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
```

Appreciate your kind help to solve this issue.

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 4):

It seems like Keycloak's docker container doesn't support it. But you can build a custom docker image to fix it. Please take a look at file [change-database.cli](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-containers/blob/master/server/tools/cli/databases/oracle/change-database.cli), there is line:

```
connection-url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@${env.DB_ADDR:oracle}:${env.DB_PORT:1521}:${env.DB_DATABASE:XE}${env.JDBC_PARAMS:}
```

And you need this line like this (slash after port instead of colon, this is required for Oracle service name to work):

```
connection-url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@${env.DB_ADDR:oracle}:${env.DB_PORT:1521}/${env.DB_DATABASE:XE}${env.JDBC_PARAMS:}
```

So change this file and build a custom Keycloak docker image. Dockerfile may look something like:

```
FROM jboss/keycloak:8.0.1
ADD /<path_on_your_system>/change-database.cli /opt/jboss/tools/cli/databases/oracle/change-database.cli
```

Comment: I have tried but i'm getting following error. `ADD failed: stat /data/DMSMobileApp/docker/tmp/docker-builder902905140/opt/jboss/tools/cli/databases/oracle/change-database.cli: no such file or directory`

Comment: My bad, in Dockerfile first should go the path to file in your system and then the path in container. I've edited the answer.

Comment: I'm new to this stuff. Can you please tell me where can i find the `change-database.cli` file. Previously what I did was clone from git repository and change the file.

Comment: You did right. Just in ADD command, it should go in this order: `ADD <modified_file> /opt/jboss/tools/cli/databases/oracle/change-database.cli`

Comment: Thank you @YuriyP, you helped me.

Comment: saved me a lot of time. this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I did these steps but unfortunately, I still have an error:
my config:
```extraEnv: |
  - name: DB_VENDOR
    value: oracle
  - name: DB_ADDR
    value: oracle-db-6-20
  - name: DB_PORT
    value: "1521"
  - name: DB_DATABASE
    value: "LVN"
  - name: DB_USER
    value: "KEYCLOAK8"
  - name: KEYCLOAK_USER
```

`LVN` is oracle `service_name`